# Powershell how to pass parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a function in a module like below:

```
function Update-QlikUser {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True,Position=0)]
    [string]$id,

    [string[]]$customProperties,
    [string[]]$tags,
    [string]$name,
    [string[]]$roles
  )

  PROCESS {
    $user = Get-QlikUser $id -raw
    If( $roles ) { $user.roles = $roles }
    If( $name ) { $user.name = $name }
    If( $customProperties ) {
      $user.customProperties = @(GetCustomProperties $customProperties)
    }
    If( $tags ) {
      $user.tags = @(GetTags $tags)
    }
    $json = $user | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 10
    return Invoke-QlikPut "/qrs/user/$id" $json
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to pass the parameter -customProperties something like follows:

```
Update-QlikUser -id "270007b2-8c8e-4b33-8b1f-b4ba7b714c95" -customProperties "User"
```

Now I know this is wrong because a custom property name has to be specified and the value for that name has to be given too. I however do not know the syntax or even what to search for which is why I need your help.

edit:
Below is the getCustomProperty function:

```
function Get-QlikCustomProperty {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$id,
    [string]$filter,
    [switch]$full,
    [switch]$raw
  )

  PROCESS {
    $path = "/qrs/custompropertydefinition"
    If( $id ) { $path += "/$id" }
    If( $full ) { $path += "/full" }
    If( $raw ) { $rawOutput = $true }
    return Invoke-QlikGet $path $filter
  }
}
```

An example I found online is as follows. please check the last line. Update-QlikUser is what I am trying to do with customproperty parameter

```
$importdata = $null

$files = Get-ChildItem $csvpath
$importdata = $files | ForEach  { Import-Csv $_  }


$allSeCpValues = $importdata.SE_Value | sort -unique
Update-QlikCustomProperty -id $(Get-QlikCustomProperty -filter "name eq '$sheetexceptioncp'").id -choiceValues $allSeCpValues

$allvaluescp = $importdata.Username | sort -unique

foreach ($userid in $allvaluescp) {
    $allcpperuser = $importdata | Where-Object { $_.Username -eq $userid }

    $allcpperuser2 = $allcpperuser.SE_Value | sort -unique | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' } | ForEach-Object {"$sheetexceptioncp=$_"}

    [array]$stringcpperuser = $null

    foreach( $cpvalue in $allcpperuser2) {
        $stringcpperuser += $cpvalue
    }

    $previousCPvalues = $(Get-QlikUser -filter "userid eq '$userid'" -full).customProperties | Where-Object { $_.definition.name -ne "$sheetexceptioncp" }

    foreach ($previousvalue in $previousCPvalues) {

        $prev = $previousvalue.definition.name + "=" + $previousvalue.value
        write-host the following previous custom properties was found:
        write-host $prev
        $stringcpperuser += $prev

    }


    write-host adding all this information to the users custom properties
    write-host $stringcpperuser


    Update-QlikUser -id $(Get-QlikUser -filter "userid eq '$userid'" -full).id -customProperties @($stringcpperuser)

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be **your** module. I suggest you take a look at how the function [GetCustomProperties](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Qlik-Admin-Utils/3.2.5.1/Content/GetCustomProperties.ps1) parses the variable `$customProperties`

Comment: Hey @LotPings, I made an edit to the question. I am still a newbie in PowerShell. Mind helping me out please?

Comment: and lol. Changed it from my module to a module!

Comment: *bump*. Anyone?

Comment: If you'd folllow my hint, you'd seen that `$customProperties` should contain (an array of)  `name=value` pairs.

Comment: I did follow your hint. The problem is I am new with PowerShell. So I am not getting the right syntax. Can you give me an example syntax please?

Comment: tried the following code which did not work `Update-QlikUser -id "270007b2-8c8e-4b33-8b1f-b4ba7b714c95" -customProperties "id eq '7942b514-56e2-45b9-9469-1c29c0904b5e' and value eq 'Test2'"`... No go

Comment: I don't know/use those cmdlets, just from reading that code I suggest `Update-QlikUser -id "270007b2-8c8e-4b33-8b1f-b4ba7b714c95" -customProperties @{'7942b514-56e2-45b9-9469-1c29c0904b5e'='Test2'}`

Comment: No luck. Still gives me that Syntax error. I found an example though. Let me post that below.

Comment: Edited the question - That last line is where he used it and supposedly gets it. I am trying to understand it but is not getting me anywhere.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks

Comment: Then share your newly gained knowledge with followup readers - or delete the question.

Comment: I did thanks. It was just no string declaration within the string. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was:

```
Update-QlikUser -id $(Get-QlikUser -filter "userid eq '$userid'" -full).id -customProperties 'Testing=Test1'
```

Or simply:

```
Update-QlikUser -id "270007b2-8c8e-4b33-8b1f-b4ba7b714c95" -customProperties 'Testing=Test1'
```